# Getting file path does not exist error when trying to load local data into snowflake table stage from Window PowerShell command line

Tags: powershell, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, command-line-interface, load

I'm trying to load local data into Snowflake (default Table Stage) using command prompts in Windows PowerShell.  I understand the correct syntax for Windows to be the following:

```
 PUT 'file://<file_path>' @%<my_table>
```

I've read through the documentation here: *https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put*
and several other sources.

I've tried the following and several variations:

a) `PUT 'file://C:\Users\asus pc\Downloads\Slate_data_files\Transactions_date_modified.csv' @%Transactions`

b) `PUT 'file://C:\Users\asus pc\Downloads\Slate_data_files\Transactions_date_modified.csv' @%Transactions AUTO COMPRESS= True OVERWRITE = True;`

I'm getting this error message:

`253006 (n/a): File doesn't exist: ['C:Usersasus pcDownloadsSlate_data_filesTransactions_date_modified.csv']`

I initially tried to load the data on the Snowflake UI in the Snowsight environment with an un-modified data set in an s3 bucket, however, the data was not loading completely because of variation in the date formatting.  So, I fixed the date format issues in the csv I had on my machine and am attempting to load it using snowsql.  However, although my code looks right, I'm not having success with this method either.  I have copied the file path appropriately and know that that file exists.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the back slashes with another back slash like this:

```
PUT 'file://C:\\Users\\asus pc\\Downloads\\Slate_data_files\\Transactions_date_modified.csv' @%Transactions AUTO COMPRESS= True OVERWRITE = True;
```